# Handling .heic files in Java

Tags: java, heif, heic

I'm trying to work with a `.heic` image in Java. Native Java cannot deal with this format. I want to either convert it to a different format (`.png` would be ideal) or convert it to a `java.awt.Image` or similar image manipulation structure. I've been searching the internet for libraries but there aren't plenty and the one I could actually use (which was ConvertApi) is not compatible with my project cause I'm using JDK 1.7 (this is non negotiable, it's not my project so I need to work with what I have) and this version of Java doesn't have the `CompletableFuture` class.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: What a clever person closed this question? 95% of Java answers recommend use of guava or commons-lang.